# A launch image named "-568h@2x.png" is required to run at native resolution on Retina 4 devices

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, splash-screen, xcode4.5

I've created a new project in XCode 4.5 and added 3 launch images for each requiered resolution. XCode created automatically 3 files: Default.png, Default@2x.png and Default-568h@2x.png

Now I get a warning demanding to create a **"-568h@2x.png"**  (no "Default" word) and offering to add the file for me. If I click "Add" it does create an empty image (black rectangle) named "-568h@2x.png".
If I don't add it, my splash screen in the run time is incorrect (it takes the app icon and stretches it to the while screen)

So I've decided to let it be and copied the Default-568h@2x.png into -568h@2x.png, it did resolve the splash screen and the warning, but now I have trouble with gitHub, since it can't work with files that start the dash "-".

Any ideas?
Where did I "lose" the "Default" prefix???

Comment: This never occurred to me and sounds really strange. But shouldn't it get called Default~568h@2x.png instead of Default-568h@2x.png?

Comment: I've tried to remove the retina 4inch image and readd it. XCode creates the file Default-568h@2x.png, but it looks like it doesn't see it in the run time, it demands to add "-568h@2x.png"

Comment: Why dont you add your own 4-inch start screen?

Comment: I did... Please reread my question.

Comment: Have you tried to make a clean build, shitf+cmd+k

Comment: Yes, I even deleted the Debug folder and rebuild from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

In your `info.plist`, see if you have the key `UILaunchImageFile~iphone`. I bet its value is empty. That key is what Xcode uses to to get the file names of the launch images. That's where you replace "Default" with "MyAwesomeLaunchImage", so your images are named `MyAwesomLaunchImage@2x.png`, etc..